# I can't delete records from MySql

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I have two tables. table a references table b I believe.

When I try to delete the package alltogether like this:

```
$query="DELETE a, b FROM classified as a, $sql_table as b WHERE a.ad_id = '$id' 
AND a.classified_id = b.classified_id AND a.poster_password='$pass'";
```

b MUST be deleted first I guess.
Even in PhpMyAdmin I cant delete a if b is still there, so I delete b first.

But what decides the order in which comes first?

The tables are alla InnoDB.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: The reason the reference key is the way it is, is because I use JOIN when I display my records... Just so you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Delete syntax is invalid. You need to do this in two statements (unless as nuqqsa mentioned, you have CASCADE DELETE enabled on the relationship between table a and table b):

```
Delete From b
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From a
                Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
                    And a.ad_id = '$id'
                    And a.classified_id = b.classified_id
                )

Delete From a
Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
    And a.ad_id = '$id'
```

What decides which comes first is the foreign keys relationships. Whichever table is the parent table must be deleted from last.

Comment: You are a SQL server user, I'm guessing?

Comment: @simplemotives - Me? I am, however the equivalent of the above syntax should work in any database product.

Comment: @Thomas - Your SQL style is all I was commenting on.

Comment: @simplemotives - Np. Although, I've worked against Oracle and I use the same style.

Comment: Thomas: Check this Q out, I am having trouble getting your code above to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972796/sql-syntax-error-little-help-please

Comment: @Camran - MySql apparently requires that you use the `From` keyword in your Delete statements and I've updated my post to reflect that. IIRC, the official SQL specification does not provide for the use of a `From` clause in a Delete statement.

Answer (score 2):

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) says about multi-table DELETE and foreign keys:

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE 
>   statement involving InnoDB tables for
>   which there are foreign key
>   constraints, **the MySQL optimizer might
>   process tables in an order that
>   differs from that of their
>   parent/child relationship**. In this
>   case, the statement fails and rolls
>   back. Instead, **you should delete from
>   a single table and rely on the ON
>   DELETE capabilities** that InnoDB
>   provides to cause the other tables to
>   be modified accordingly.

So that when a record in your main table is deleted, so are its foreign references, e.g:

```
ALTER TABLE products
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
      FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id, supplier_name)
      REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id, supplier_name)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```