# Sql syntax error

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

Here is my query:

```
$query="Delete b
Where Exists 
    (
        Select 1
        From a
        Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
        And a.ad_id = '$id'
        And a.classified_id = b.classified_id
    )
Delete a
Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
And a.ad_id = '$id'";
```

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where Exists ( Select 1 From a Where a.poster_p' at line 2

If you need more input let me know...

Whats wrong here?

Thanks

**UDPATE:**

Just a Q: Do I need to specify also that a = "this table" and b = "another table" or does MySql get that by this code?

As for the new code posted where to use FROM and a terminator semicolon, wont work and give this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Delete FROM a Where a.poster_password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' at line 10

**UPDATE2:**

```
$query="Delete FROM $sql_table
        Where Exists 
        (
            Select 1
            From classified
            Where classified.poster_password = '$pass'
            And classified.ad_id = '$id'
            And classified.classified_id = $sql_table.classified_id
        );
        Delete FROM classified
        Where classified.poster_password = '$pass'
        And classified.ad_id = '$id'";
```

And when I `echo $query`: (fordon is in this case `$sql_table` variable.)

```
Delete FROM fordon 
Where Exists 
(  
     Select 1 
     From classified 
     Where classified.poster_password = 'xxxxx' 
     And classified.ad_id = 'motorbat_166250627' 
     And classified.classified_id = fordon.classified_id 
 ); 
 Delete FROM classified 
 Where classified.poster_password = 'xxxxx' 
 And classified.ad_id = 'motorbat_166250627'
```

Thanks again

Comment: Did you try to remove the second query (`Delete a`) and only execute the first one?

Comment: I think it was mysql version 5.1 btw... Peter: No I haven't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the tables to delete from. Try:

```
$query="Delete FROM b
Where Exists 
    (
        Select 1
        From a
        Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
        And a.ad_id = '$id'
        And a.classified_id = b.classified_id
    );
Delete FROM a
Where a.poster_password = '$pass'
And a.ad_id = '$id'";
```

I've also added in a semicolon after the end of the first DELETE query.  If you want to run both at the same time, you'll need a separator to terminate the first query, before you run the second version.

**Re.** your question edit about MySQL "getting" the tables - if `a` and `b` are aliases here, then no, MySQL doesn't know what `a` and `b` are.  You'll need to alias the tables, or replace `a` and `b` with the actual table names.

Comment: Check my update please, this wont work either for some reason

Comment: Okay, changed the aliases, but still get the same error in the update of my Q... hmm

Comment: Can you post your exact query string now?

Answer (score 0):

The two deletes need to be separate statements  ( and executed separately ).

Comment: MySQL supposts multi-table deletes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html. However the OP's syntax appears incorrect. There should be a `FROM` in there.